# wpa_supplicant.conf permission

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, troubleshooting, file-permissions, wpa-supplicant

So I'm facing this problem for a while now . What happens is that my phone reboots automatically sometimes and after the reboot I can't use my WiFi . The button is stuck at off:

[image: screenshot]

So after doing some research on this I wiped my `/data/misc/WiFi` folder to fix it (didn't create a backup though). So the problem got fixed but it came back again. So I wiped again and it didn't work this time.

In order to restore the folder I copied the WPA_supplicant files in the folder manually. But I don't know what permission to set it to . And even if I change the permissions it gets reverted back to 0660. Also I don't know whether the the `.conf` file is even compatible for my phone as I got that one from an XDA post.

[image: Screenshot]

Can anybody guide me how I can fix this ?

Comment: It's not just the permissions, it's also the ownership – which is not clear from your description/screenshots. Not sure if there are device specific differences; AFAIR they must be owned by `system`, but I cannot remember the group.

Comment: @Izzy `wifi:wifi` in my stock Android 6.0.1. :)

Comment: once you restored the permissions and owner/group, you may need to run this from the adb shell: `restorecon -Rv /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Answer (score 1):

On my phone permissions and ownership looks like:

```
ls -las /data/misc/wifi/
12 drwxrwx---  4 wifi   wifi    4096 2017-08-14 16:30 .
 8 drwxrwx--t 39 system misc    4096 2017-08-12 20:54 ..
 8 -rw-rw----  1 system wifi      21 2017-08-14 16:30 entropy.bin
48 -rw-rw----  1 system wifi   43098 2017-08-12 22:36 hostapd.conf
 8 -rw-------  1 system system  3136 2017-08-12 23:27 ipconfig.txt
52 -rw-------  1 system system 44517 2017-08-14 16:30 networkHistory.txt
 4 -rw-rw----  1 wifi   wifi     186 2017-08-14 16:30 p2p_supplicant.conf
12 drwxrwx---  2 wifi   wifi    4096 2017-08-14 16:30 sockets
 8 -rw-------  1 system system    20 2017-08-12 22:36 softap.conf
12 drwxrwx---  2 wifi   wifi    4096 1970-01-10 00:56 wpa_supplicant
16 -rw-rw----  1 wifi   wifi   10957 2017-08-14 16:30 wpa_supplicant.conf
```